# How to use PagerAdapter to set Imageview from Arraylist using getters and setters?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

My application uses Jake Wharten's View pager Indicator library.

I get set of images from json data. Using getters and setters I store and retrieve values.

**MainActivty.java**

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String text) {
        //Close progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        JSONArray ja;

        try {
            ja = new JSONArray(text);
            int len = ja.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                JSONObject json_data = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                name_full = json_data.getString("name");
                descp_full = json_data.getString("description");
                image_full = json_data.getString("image");
                price_full = json_data.getString("price");

                GettersandSetters rData1 = new GettersandSetters();
                rData1.setFull_grid_name(name_full);

                numbers = json_data.getString(("image")).split(",");


                rData1.setFull_grid_image(numbers);

                rData1.setFull_grid_price(price_full);
                rData1.setDescription_full(descp_full);


                val_grid_full.add(rData1);
                name.setText(name_full);
                price.setText(rate + (price_full));
                des.setText(description + "\n\n" + (descp_full));
               Picasso.with(context_tab1).load(image).into(fullimage);

                // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
                viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
                adapter = new Sliding_Images_Adapter(FullImage.this, val_grid_full);
                // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

                // ViewPager Indicator
                mIndicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
                mIndicator.setFades(false);
                mIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class Sliding_Images_Adapter extends PagerAdapter {
private String[] IMAGES;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
ArrayList<GettersandSetters> val;
GettersandSetters row1 = new GettersandSetters();

public Sliding_Images_Adapter(Context context,ArrayList<GettersandSetters> val) {
    this.context = context;
    this.val=val;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return val.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    row1 = val.get(position);
    // Declare Variables

    ImageView imgflag;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_with_images, container,
            false);
    // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
    imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_full);
    // Capture position and set to the ImageView
    Picasso.with(context).load("xxx" + row1.getImage()).into(imgflag);

    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}
}
```

slider_with_images.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="1dip" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/image_full"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Through Debug option I could able to see that I pass the values to the Adapter class.

**Problem**

But I am not sure how to set the image in the adapter class.

Thanks.

Comment: http://selvin.pl/SimpleCursorPagerAdapter.java.txt <= ok it is for CursorAdapter ... but you can easily change it to BaseAdapter ... now you can build your own BaseAdapter implementation (same as for the listviews) and use it as PagerAdapter ... it will also reuse the views :)

Comment: *But I am not sure how to set the image in the adapter class.* but you are doing this in `instantiateItem` ... what is your problem then? ... about your code ... it looks ok .. I would add some canceling Picasso request in destroyItem ...

Comment: Hey thanks , actually the imageview is null here.Iam not sure how to set the image exactly in PagerAdapter.

Comment: if imgflag is null then obviously slider_with_images layout doesn't contains ImageView with id == image_full ... end of story